# Copying bookmarks from a crashed Ubuntu disk?

Tags: bookmarks

My Ubuntu disk crashed and I need to get a copy for my bookmarks. I tried accessing `.mozilla` (for my firefox bookmarks) inside my home folder by booting through a bootable cd for Ubuntu, however it tells me I don't have permissions to access the folder. How can I copy the `bookmarks.html`?

I also need to copy bookmarks for the Chrome browser.

Comment: Did you try to elevate your rights by sudo in terminal?

Comment: I'm trying to do this through the graphical interface. I thought about sudo in terminal but then I thought what I do command line might not be applicable on the graphical interface. Also these two are different installations( bootable cd and crashed disk), so permissions on one might not be applicable to the other?? Just to let you know I'm not quiet proficient with the command line. It's been a long time since I used it.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question exactly, but might be useful after: Firefox doesn't use bookmarks.html anymore; bookmarks are stored in an sqlite database, and bookmark backups are stored as .json files (you probably want the latest backup).

Comment: Also, the `nautilus-admin` package might be useful to open a folder as root so that you can access all files and/or change permissions (but be sure to close the root nautilus window as soon as you don't need it anymore!)

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't encrypt you home folder, take out that drive and insert it as a secondary drive into a Windows Computer. Windows ignores Linux permissions.